# Why is my app using the default method vs the method I imported?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have a context processor where I'm trying to override get_and_delete_messages

```
from forum.user_messages import get_and_delete_messages  
def user_messages (request):  
    """
    Returns session messages for the current session.  
    """
    messages = request.user.get_and_delete_messages()  
    return { 'user_messages': messages }
```

It's not picking up a user message that I can see in the debugging session:

```
ipdb> request.session['messages']  
["only site Admins can use that feature."]
```

The app seems to be calling the get_and_delete_messages from the User model @ django.contrib.auth.models:

Instead of the method I imported.

How do I get the correct model called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import `get_and_delete_messages`, you are importing a function with that name. `request.user.get_and_delete_messages` is still bound to the same function implementation that it was bound to before.